# How to combine ranges in VBA?

Tags: forms, vba, excel, printing

I have a form that I have developed in Excel and added a command button to print the form.  There are four pages to the form, but if the first cell of the second or third pages of the cell are blank, I want to skip those pages.  I have come up with the following code, but i get an "Type Mismatch" error as it combines the ranges. Is this not an appropriate way to combine ranges/ is there a better way?

```
Private Sub PrintAuth1_Click()
'   Prints the Authorization Form upon clicking once

Dim printrng As Range   'Range to be printed so that blank pages are not printed.
    Set printrng = Worksheets("BLR 13210").Range("A1:AX69")
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

If ws.Range("E75") <> "" Then   'If first line of this page is blank, then it won't print the page
    printrng = printrng & ws.Range("A70:AX135")
End If
If ws.Range("E141") <> "" Then  'If first line of this page is blank, then it won't print the page
    printrng = printrng & ws.Range("A136:AX200")
End If

printrng = printrng & ws.Range("A201:AX264")    'Adds last page to print range

' Dialog Box to decide whether to quick print or make changes to printer setup.
msg = "Would you like to send to default printer?"
msg = msg & vbNewLine
config = vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1
Title = "Printer Selection"
ans = MsgBox(msg, config, Title)

If ans = vbYes Then printrng.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
If ans = vbNo Then Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
If ans = vbCancel Then
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Union` function `set  printrng = Union(printrng , ws.Range("A70:AX135"))`. Also for the last bit where you check the user response, use `If .... ElseIf.... Else.. End If`

Comment: why cant you say Range("thisrange, thatrange, another range") ??

Comment: Thanks cyboashu.  That is really what I was looking for.  It makes it easy to then copy and past the code into several of my forms.

Comment: Just be aware that using 'Union' will fail if one of the ranges is null, so you should add in some error checking as well.